# C - OpenSSL AES Encryption key issue

Tags: c, openssl, key, aes, ecb

I'm porting an AES encryption procedure from Javascript to C.

I'm using **OpenSSL**.

For the encryption I'm using **ECB 256** mode.

The encryption goes successfully but the final Base64 **does not correspond** to the result I get in JS.

By testing with several online tools, the output I was getting from the C version was actually correct but different from the one from JS.

Then I realized the problem thanks to this tool https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef.

The key I'm providing is a **MD5 hash** like this:
aa8744256a89cba0d77f0686916f8b2e

If I pass the key as an **HEX string** in the CyberChef tool, the output corresponds to the JS version.

The C version is reading the key as an **UTF string**.

How can I force it to read the key as an HEX string?

Here's the code:

```
//generating MD5 of key
char keyHash[33];
unsigned char digest[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
MD5((unsigned char*)keyString, strlen(keyString), (unsigned char*)&digest);
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    sprintf(&keyHash[i * 2], "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[i]);

char out[256];
int outlen = 0;
//initializing context
EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
//inizializing encryption with 256 ECB Cipher and MD5 Hash as Key
EVP_EncryptInit(ctx, EVP_aes_256_ecb(), keyHash, 0);
//setting padding
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, EVP_PADDING_PKCS7);
//encrypting
EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, out, &outlen, user, strlen(user));
EVP_EncryptFinal(ctx, out, &outlen);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

//parsing the result to Base64
BIO *mbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO *b64bio = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
BIO_set_flags(b64bio, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
BIO *bio = BIO_push(b64bio, mbio);

BIO_write(bio, out, outlen);
BIO_flush(bio);

char* data = NULL;
size_t datalen = 0;
datalen = BIO_get_mem_data(mbio, &data);
data[datalen] = '\0';

//printing the result
printf("encrypted data: [%s]\n", data);
```

Comment: What happens if you do not perform the hexadecimal encoding, but initialize the digest with 32 bytes instead of 16 and set the rightmost bytes to all zero? Then you use the digest as key.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I tried with 32 bytes digest but still not working as expected.

Comment: Hmm, which encodings have you specified for cyberchef for the key, input and output?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes As I wrote, if I give HEX as the key encoding it works as expected. If I set it to UTF-8, it gives same result I get in this C code. The output is set to RAW. Same goes for the input payload.
Mode is ECB. 
Then I added Base64 at last to encode the output.

Comment: The problem with that is that the encoded key in hex is smaller than 32 bytes or 256 bits after decoding, as required for AES. That's why I tried the zero bytes trick. Are you sure you don't need AES-128? Because that would make more sense and that's what the CyberChef will do. So just use digest without hex encoding, and with AES-128.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes YES. That was it! I tried using AES-128 but I didn't try using the digest instead of the hash. I did it now and it worked! Dunno why I was going for 256. My mistake, I guess. Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that using `strlen` is very dangerous here, and ECB is never very secure. But alright, glad you made it. Remember, hex is just *a representation* of the bytes, not the bytes themselves.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I'm well aware of ECB insecurities but this is what the JS library used and I had to parse. Thanks for the heads up. This was my very first time programming in C.

Comment: Congrats. I don't know why you needed to go for a lower level language, but here you are. And now I'll try and get some sleep, I'm already late.